# Upgrade with ISO - User Name, password, computer name

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, live-cd

Try a update from 12.04.4 to 14.04.1 by using the ISO (USB) as I had a live session with 14.04.1 to test if it runs on my computer
Upgrade process detected 12.04 version but later in the install ask me for Name, Username, password and computer name.

As I was doing an upgrade I didn't know what to do here. 
What is the suggest approach?

- Type the exact same info as used back in the 12.04 install?
- Just user name and password must match?

btw, I did cancel the wizard as I wanted to start the upgrade from my 12.04 install but the cancel left my 12.04 in a "half upgrade" state mess, which require me to do a fresh install.

Update:
I'm good with this system for now, but for next upgrade (have other system) what is the right approach here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done a fresh install after a mess up, it won't make much difference, your data is probably lost.

If it isn't lost and you want it, then I advise that you enter everything the same (although it may not allow the same system name). If it is lost, you need to look into recovering it first. Use the live CD to browse the hard drive and copy it off to an external hard drive or network computer. If not, do a search for data recovery tools.

If you don't care about the data that was there, go wild! Enter whatever you want there. I suggest `wombatjellyfishcathippo` as a system name.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my system is good just want to know what I "should" have done here to not end in the mess :-)